# Why the mongodb query is not returning the result

Tags: mongodb, mgo

I'm using `$lookup` with `$match` aggregation to fetch the result from the two collections on the basis of particular condition. Below is my query Which I'm using in golang code :-

```
 getCollection := sessionCopy.DB("Database").C("lead_section")
pipe := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{
    bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"status": 1}},
    bson.M{
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "localField":   "_id",
            "from":         "lead_field",
            "foreignField": "lead_section_id",
            "as":           "custom_fields"}},
    // bson.M{"$unwind": "$custom_fields.status"},
    bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"custom_fields.status": 1}}})
```

above query will returning me this result

```
 [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Message",
            "status": 1,
            "custom_fields": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "lead_section_id": 1,
                    "field_type": "text",
                    "help_text": "This is a tool tip",
                    "name": "Test11",
                    "status": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "lead_section_id": 1,
                    "field_type": "text",
                    "help_text": "This is a tool tip",
                    "name": "Test11",
                    "status": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "lead_section_id": 1,
                    "field_type": "text",
                    "help_text": "This is a tool tip",
                    "name": "Test11",
                    "status": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

but I want the result produce by the pipe is with only `status 1`. But in `custom_fields` the first record with `id:3` having `status:0`

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this you would need to use a [`$lookup` with multiple join conditions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup).

For example (using the mongo shell):

```
db.lead_section.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        status: 1
    }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: "lead_field",    
        let: { lead_section: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
            { $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $and: [
                        { $eq: [ "$lead_section_id", "$$lead_section" ] },                        
                        { $eq: [ "$status", 1 ] }
                    ]
                }
            }},            
        ],
        as: "custom_fields"
    }}
])
```

Comment: can you tell me that how we will pass array of `[1,0]` in this line of the query `{ $eq: [ "$status", 1 ] }`

Comment: And also tell me that If i want to fetch a specific record like from section collection `"_id":1` then the fields of the particular section will be in the array

Answer (score 0):

This is how `$match` works with array fields. It looks for match in any of the subdocuments. In this case, the other two subdocuments (ids 4 and 5) have status 1, so the whole structure is considered a match and is passed on further.

In other words, it filters top level documents. It does not filter nested arrays.

Comment: Can you tell that then what is the query

Comment: @puneet55667788: what do you mean "what is the query"?

Comment: Can you tell me what changes I hav eto do in my query